# Can't scrap all page with extensive scrolling

Tags: python, facebook, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, infinite-scroll

I'm attempting to scrape content from specific pages on Facebook. The process involves scrolling through a page with a very long list of posts. This strategy worked quite well on Instagram, which employs dynamic loading; however, on Facebook, each scroll seems to trigger a complete update of the entire page.

So, for pages with a substantial number of posts, each scroll took about few minutes for a full page refresh. And finally I got an "Out of memory" error.

[image]

Is there a way that could prevent the entire page from refreshing on each scroll? I'm looking for a more efficient method to scrape without reloading all content continuously.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!